# MySQL - PHP unique values from rows

Tags: php, mysql

I have this table:
table 1

```html
+----+-----------------------+----------+------+-------+
| ID | COUNTRY               | QUANTITY | EACH | PRICE |
+----+-----------------------+----------+------+-------+
| 1  | U.S.A                 |     1    |  12  | 1*12  |
| 2  | U.K.                  |     2    |   3  | 2* 3  |
| 3  | GERMANY               |   NULL   |   3  |       |
| 4  | FRANCE;GERMANY; U.S.A |     0    |   7  |       |
| 5  | U.S.A;GERMANY         |     3    |   8  | 3*8   |
| 6  | FRANCE;U.K.           |     1    |  10  | 1*10  |
| 7  | U.S.A;FRANCE          |     2    |   6  | 2*6   |
| 8  | FRANCE;FRANCE         |     9    |   3  | 9*3   |
+----+-----------------------+----------+------+-------+
```

and this code sql:

```js
SELECT
  COUNTRY,
  SUM(COALESCE(IF(QUANTITY = NULL OR QUANTITY = 0,1,QUANTITY), 1) * EACH) AS PRICE
FROM table1
GROUP BY COUNTRY
```

How could I make unique values for the country column and return: USA = 48 (ID: 1+5+7); UK= 6; GERMANY=3; FRANCE = 44 (ID: 4+6+8). I want that the rows, those contain two, three, four countries to be eliminated and to remain only the first country from row. 
Thank you!

Comment: That's a terrible table. You should have one country per `COUNTRY` row. Then you relate different countries through a common mapping. The only way you can do this is to query the table, then compare the strings. Which ignores everything about the database design.

Comment: Wait...do you want to _eliminate_ records with more than one country, or do you want to _retain_ them but keep only the first country?

Comment: You would fix the data model to have a table with one row per `id` and country.  That is the SQLish way to represent a list -- not a delimited separated list.

Comment: That being said, if you need CSV presentation, you could always aggregate using `GROUP_CONCAT`.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen I don't want to eliminate records, I only want to keep the first country.

Comment: @Aaron I know that the table is terrible, it's actually an old table and I have to adapt myself to this.

Comment: this is a bad design

Comment: BTW, there's no need for `COALESCE`. The `IF` prevents any null values from being produced.

Comment: or better yet design the db to do joins

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`substring_index`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) to get the first country in the `;`-separated list.

```
SELECT
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(COUNTRY, ';', 1) AS COUNTRY
  SUM(IF(QUANTITY IS NULL OR QUANTITY = 0,1,QUANTITY) * EACH) AS PRICE
FROM table1
GROUP BY COUNTRY
```

It would be much more complicated if you wanted to keep all the rows where each country appears (in that case I would recommend doing it in PHP, not MySQL, since MySQL doesn't have a builtin way to do `explode()`).

Comment: `QUANTITY = NULL` should be changed to `QUANTITY IS NULL`. That is why OP used `COALESCE`.